# Let $f,g$ be holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$ that are continuous in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Show that if $f=g$ on $|z|=1$, then $f=g$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g$ be holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$ that are continuous in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Show that if $f=g$ on $|z|=1$, then $f=g$

It seems like identity theorem. But they have to be equal on an open connected set.  $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is not open so I cannot use the identity theorem. At least directly.

Comment: Use the maximum modulus principle on $f-g$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\varphi=f-g$, then $\varphi$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ and thus
$$ \forall z\in\mathbb{D},|\varphi(z)|\leqslant\max_{|u|=1}|\varphi(u)|=0 $$
and thus $\varphi=0$ on $\mathbb{D}$ and $f=g$ on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Comment: Can this be generalized to any part of the circle somehow? I feel like you can weaken the assumption to say that they only agree on 1/4 of a circle. What do you think? Btw, very cool solution.

Comment: It works with any part of the circle as long as you can show that $\max_{|u|=1}|\varphi(u)|=0$, that is to say $f=g$ on $|z|=1$. We can suppose that $f=g$ on a dense subset of $|z|=1$ (which is equivalent to $f=g$ on $|z|=1$ since $f$ and $g$ are continuous). If $f\neq g$ on a "large" part of $|z|=1$ then $\max_{|u|=1}|\varphi(u)|>0$ and we can't deduce that $f=g$. I think we can find an example of $f$ and $g$ holomorphic such that $f\neq g$ on a large part of $|z|=1$ and $f=g$ on the other part but with $f\neq g$ on $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: The result holds as long as $f=g$ on a set of non zero measure on the unit circle and it is called Privalov theorem (continuity can be relaxed to what are called non-tangetial limits being equal but not to radial limits only); the general proof requires some work but in the case of an arc of any positive length however small, the reflection principle gives immediately the result