# Let $f,g$ be holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on$\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Show that if $f=g$ on $|z|=1$ s.t $\Re(z),\Im(z)>0$ then $f=g$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g$ be holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on$\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Show that if $f=g$ on $|z|=1$ s.t $\Re(z),\Im(z)>0$ then $f=g$

A weaker question was asked here: [Let $f,g$ be holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$ that are continuous in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Show that if $f=g$ on $|z|=1$, then $f=g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768199/let-f-g-be-holomorphic-function-in-mathbbd-that-are-continuous-in-overl)

But i am certain we can loosen the condition to just some part of the circle. I was wondering how would the proof go. And idea I had was to consider our region, then the maximum of $f-g$ over that part is on the lines going towards the origin. Now somehow use maximum modulus principle on the whole circle, but I am not sure how to do that. Perhaps the reflection principle will be useful here?

Comment: you can use the reflection principle to extend $f-g=h$ to an analytic function across the arc where it is zero and then the identity principle shows $h$ identically zero, so $f=g$; another idea is to rotate $h=0$ on a small arc to cover the full circle by taking $h(z)h(e^{it_1}z)...h(e^{it_n}z)$ for an as fine partition of the circle as you need so $e^{it_k}z$ cover the circle for $z$ in your arc (here $4$ terms are enough clearly)

Comment: Just apply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683915/prove-that-fz-0-for-all-z-in-overlined0-1 to $f-g$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reflection is indeed the way to go.

Restrict $h=f-g$ to $\mathbb{D}\cup\{\lvert z\rvert=1: \Re z,\Im z>0\}$ and reflection $h(z)=\overline{h(1/\bar{z})}$ gives a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}-\{\lvert z\rvert=1:\Re z\leq 0\text{ or }\Im z\leq 0\}$ which is $0$ on the arc.  Hence $f=g$ outside the 3/4-circular arc and hence $f=g$ everywhere.