# if $f=g$ in $\partial D$ prove that $f=g$ in $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f,g$ be 2 holomorphic functions on the open bounded and connected space $D$ they are also continuous in $\overline{D}$, if $f=g$ in $\partial D$ prove that $f=g$ in $D$

My first thought was to take a sequence in $D$ with limit on  $\partial D$ and show somehow that the limit is in $D$ and then use a theorem which I don't know how its call is English to show that $f=g$ in $D$, but now I think this is a wrong way to do it because $D$ is open, also I can't expand $f$ or $g$ because I don't know if they are holomorphic outside of $D$,

**any hints?**

Comment: Do you know the maximum principle?

Comment: @UmbertiP. Or, for a more concrete / direct solution, Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: This is for the unit disk, but the proof is the same in the general case: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3768199/42969

Comment: @MartinR  thanks! I am new to the maximum principle the identity theorem ect and I needed some hints.